# Stability of system of ordinary nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

**Question: where are my mistakes?** (I was told that this does not prove stability)

In my thesis I am trying to show that this system is stable only when $w> \widetilde{w}$:

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$
$\begin{align}
  \dot{y}(t) & =\big(n(t)f(w, \widetilde{w}) + \dot{n}(t)m( \widetilde{w} )\big) \tanh\Big(\lambda_1 \big( y_B-y(t) \big) \Big) \\
  \dot{n}(t) & =a (w-\widetilde{w})\tanh \Big(\lambda_2 \big(n_B-n(t)\big)\Big)
\end{align}$

Since my Jacobian matrix is "too wide" lets look at each element seperately. So my Jacobian matrix:

$\begin{align*}
  J=\begin{bmatrix}
   J_{11}    &  J_{12}\\
 J_{21}  & J_{22}\\[0.5cm]
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$

Thus,

$J_{11} = -\big(n(t)f(w, \widetilde{w})+\dot{n}(t)m(\widetilde{w}))\big) \lambda_1 \sech^2(\lambda_1 (y_B-y(t)) $

$J_{12} = -m(\widetilde{w})a(w-\widetilde{w})\lambda_2\sech^2(\lambda_2 (n_B-n(t)) \tanh\big(\lambda_1 (y_B-y(t))\big) $

$J_{21} = 0$

$J_{22} = -a(w-\widetilde{w})\lambda_2\sech^2(\lambda_2 (n_B-n(t)) $

Here, $a>0$, $\lambda_1>0$, $\lambda_2>0$, functions $f$ and $m$ can only be positive values.  We have an equiliubrium values $(y_B,n_B)$:

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
 \begin{align*}
J_{(y_B,n_B)}=
  \small{\begin{bmatrix}
   -n(t)f(w, \widetilde{w})\lambda_1 &      0  \\
   0           & -a(w-\widetilde{w})\lambda_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}
 \end{align*}$

We know that $-n(t)f(w, \widetilde{w})\lambda_1$ is always negative. Lets say that $w>\widetilde{w}$ then $ -a(w-\widetilde{w})\lambda_2$ is also negative. Then we have an asymptotic stability.